# Why is CoreImage `CIContext.render()` executing this EXC_BAD_ACCESS error during rendering?

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access, core-image

**Edit6:**

So, I believe this is a threading problem. Some kind of concurrency or race condition that happens arbitrarily. My current setup creates a variable, let image = self.videoImage and somewhere between threads either image or self.videoImage is freeing memory somewhere and other threads access is causing issues. The goal is to utilize a different technique will deploying threads and ensure data is prepared.

I am rendering a `CIImage` using

```
if(ciImage == nil) { print("CIImage nil") }
if(currentDrawable == nil) { print("Draw nil") }
if(currentDrawable.texture == nil) { print("Text nil") }
if(commandBuffer == nil) { print("CB nil") }
if(ciImage.extent == nil) { print("Extent nil") }
if(ciContext == nil) { print("Context nil") }
if(colorSpace == nil) { print("CS nil") }
ciContext.render(ciImage, to: currentDrawable.texture, commandBuffer: commandBuffer, bounds: ciImage.extent, colorSpace: colorSpace)
```

I am printing out `nil` because I was trying to determine the cause of my `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error which I believe generally stems from accessing bad memory, or a variable that is not there anymore. Yet, I am still getting the error without obtaining a `nil` message. Why would I be getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error during a `CIContext.render()` call?

[image: excbadaccess]

Edit: Here is the entire method. I showed the picture to illustrate where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is. For @Shauket's comment, if the `CIImage` was nil prior, it would have given an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` prior to the call.

Note: *This happens what seems randomly; obviously there is a reason, but it is very sporadic. It could happen the first time or the millionth time I call this method.*

```
    func update(with ciImage: CIImage) {
        // Wait to ensure only kMaxBuffersInFlight are getting proccessed by any stage in the Metal
        // pipeline (App, Metal, Drivers, GPU, etc)
        let _ = inFlightSemaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
        guard
            let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(),
            let currentDrawable = renderDestination.currentDrawable
            else {
                inFlightSemaphore.signal()
                return
        }
        commandBuffer.label = "MyCommand"

        commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler{ [weak self] commandBuffer in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                strongSelf.inFlightSemaphore.signal()
            }
        }
        //Won't ever get here if simulator because I also check this inside RealTimeDepthViewController but need to check so the pod will compile
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        #else
        if(ciImage == nil) { print("CIImage nil") }
        if(currentDrawable == nil) { print("Draw nil") }
        if(currentDrawable.texture == nil) { print("Text nil") }
        if(commandBuffer == nil) { print("CB nil") }
        if(ciImage.extent == nil) { print("Extent nil") }
        if(ciContext == nil) { print("Context nil") }
        if(colorSpace == nil) { print("CS nil") }
        ciContext.render(ciImage, to: currentDrawable.texture, commandBuffer: commandBuffer, bounds: ciImage.extent, colorSpace: colorSpace)

        commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
        #endif
    }
```

Additionally, this is the backtrace.

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x13b00021d)
    frame #0: 0x0000000196fce0a0 CoreImage`CI::ColorKernelImage::child_count() const + 100
    frame #1: 0x0000000196fff704 CoreImage`CI::GraphObject::traverse_unique(CI::GraphObject*, void (CI::GraphObject*, CI::GraphObject*, int, int, int) block_pointer) + 244
    frame #2: 0x0000000197003b30 CoreImage`CI::prepare_initial_graph(CI::Context*, char const*, CI::Image*, CI::RenderDestination const*, CGRect, CGColorSpace*, CI::PixelFormat, CI::swizzle_info, CI::Affine const&, bool, CI::TextureDescriptor*) + 300
    frame #3: 0x0000000197005750 CoreImage`CI::image_render(char const*, CI::Context*, CI::Image*, CI::RenderDestination const*) + 196
    frame #4: 0x00000001970031a0 CoreImage`CI::RenderToTexture<CI::Texture>::render_to_texture(CI::Image*, CI::Context*, CGSize const&, CI::Texture) const + 88
    frame #5: 0x00000001970034d8 CoreImage`CI::RenderToMTLTexture::render(CI::Image*, CI::Context*) const + 236
    frame #6: 0x0000000196f0f9d4 CoreImage`-[CIRenderDestination _render:withContext:] + 72
    frame #7: 0x0000000196f1354c CoreImage`-[CIContext(CIRenderDestination) _startTaskToRender:toDestination:forPrepareRender:forClear:error:] + 2824
    frame #8: 0x0000000196f12a28 CoreImage`-[CIContext(CIRenderDestination) startTaskToRender:fromRect:toDestination:atPoint:error:] + 144
    frame #9: 0x0000000196e2b398 CoreImage`-[CIContext render:toMTLTexture:commandBuffer:bounds:colorSpace:] + 472
  * frame #10: 0x0000000104b76024 DepthCamera`MetalRenderer.update(ciImage=0x000000010994d810, self=<unavailable>) at MetalRenderer.swift:81:19 [opt]
    frame #11: 0x0000000104b8ea2c DepthCamera`specialized RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.draw(self=0x0000000109c17c80) at RealTimeDepthViewController.swift:543:26 [opt]
    frame #12: 0x0000000104b843d0 DepthCamera`merged @objc DepthCamera.RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.buttonClicked(sender: __C.UIButton) -> () + 60
    frame #13: 0x00000001af4d2380 MetalKit`-[MTKView draw] + 184
    frame #14: 0x00000001af4ce8d0 MetalKit`-[MTKViewDisplayLinkTarget draw] + 40
    frame #15: 0x000000010524c208 GPUToolsCore`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 172
    frame #16: 0x000000019c051f24 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 628
    frame #17: 0x000000019c120608 QuartzCore`display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 268
    frame #18: 0x000000019551ddac CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 176
    frame #19: 0x00000001955487c4 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 60
    frame #20: 0x0000000195547e90 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 448
    frame #21: 0x0000000195542ac8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2144
    frame #22: 0x0000000195541f40 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
    frame #23: 0x000000019f7d2534 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 108
    frame #24: 0x00000001996cd580 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1940
    frame #25: 0x0000000102a78d38 ARMail`main at AppDelegate.swift:13:7 [opt]
    frame #26: 0x00000001953c0e18 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

**Edit2:**

I have now figured out that the issue is `currentDrawable`. The below image illustrates that the variable `currentDrawable` is not nil right before the `cicontext.render` but it IS nil (address 0x0) at the time of the call.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview/1535971-currentdrawable) states

> If all drawable objects are in use, the value of this property is nil. Your app should check that currentDrawable isn’t nil before attempting to draw. The view changes the value of this property only after returning from a drawing function, either draw(_:) from a subclassed instance of the view, or draw(in:) from the view’s delegate. In my case, this method is only called within my draw method.

```
extension RealtimeDepthMaskViewController: MTKViewDelegate {
    public func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        if(renderer.checkRenderCurrentDrawable()) { 
            renderer.update(with: image)
            if(self.finalImage != nil) {
                self.finalImage = image
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Draw nil")
        }
    }
}

func checkRenderCurrentDrawable() -> Bool {
    return self.renderDestination.currentDrawable != nil
}
```

So, I check if it is `nil`, it is not at the time, then at the time of `cicontext.render` it becomes nil...

**Edit3:**

Still looking into it, but obtained this on the last test...

```
020-03-12 02:20:51.289750-0400 ARMail[6169:1212379] Compiler failed to build request
2020-03-12 02:20:51.289963-0400 ARMail[6169:1212379] Metal library creation failed: Error Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Function _blendWithMaskB0 argument  marked as info type Output for function composition has different type <4 x float> than the source function _ci_early_out return type i1" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Function _blendWithMaskB0 argument  marked as info type Output for function composition has different type <4 x float> than the source function _ci_early_out return type
```

**Edit4:**

Similar backtrace below; after much testing, it seems that sometimes `self` is the bad address. Or `currentDrawable.texture` is the bad address. Or `ciImage` is the bad address. However, in the end all be all, more than the rest, `ciImage` is the culprit which provides the bad address. Below the backtrace is a snippet indicating that the address for `ciImage` cannot be obtained, which seems like it is the bad address. However, I'm still not sure why, because `ciImage` is not nil 0.125 secs before when I print out `ciImage`.

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa9601760910)
    frame #0: 0x0000000196fce0a0 CoreImage`CI::ColorKernelImage::child_count() const + 100
    frame #1: 0x0000000196fff704 CoreImage`CI::GraphObject::traverse_unique(CI::GraphObject*, void (CI::GraphObject*, CI::GraphObject*, int, int, int) block_pointer) + 244
    frame #2: 0x0000000197003b30 CoreImage`CI::prepare_initial_graph(CI::Context*, char const*, CI::Image*, CI::RenderDestination const*, CGRect, CGColorSpace*, CI::PixelFormat, CI::swizzle_info, CI::Affine const&, bool, CI::TextureDescriptor*) + 300
    frame #3: 0x0000000197005750 CoreImage`CI::image_render(char const*, CI::Context*, CI::Image*, CI::RenderDestination const*) + 196
    frame #4: 0x00000001970031a0 CoreImage`CI::RenderToTexture<CI::Texture>::render_to_texture(CI::Image*, CI::Context*, CGSize const&, CI::Texture) const + 88
    frame #5: 0x00000001970034d8 CoreImage`CI::RenderToMTLTexture::render(CI::Image*, CI::Context*) const + 236
    frame #6: 0x0000000196f0f9d4 CoreImage`-[CIRenderDestination _render:withContext:] + 72
    frame #7: 0x0000000196f1354c CoreImage`-[CIContext(CIRenderDestination) _startTaskToRender:toDestination:forPrepareRender:forClear:error:] + 2824
    frame #8: 0x0000000196f12a28 CoreImage`-[CIContext(CIRenderDestination) startTaskToRender:fromRect:toDestination:atPoint:error:] + 144
    frame #9: 0x0000000196e2b398 CoreImage`-[CIContext render:toMTLTexture:commandBuffer:bounds:colorSpace:] + 472
  * frame #10: 0x0000000105e00c1c DepthCamera`MetalRenderer.update(ciImage=<unavailable>, self=0x000000028105c320) at MetalRenderer.swift:86:19 [opt]
    frame #11: 0x0000000105e0d3c8 DepthCamera`specialized RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.draw(self=0x000000010983ba00) at RealTimeDepthViewController.swift:556:30 [opt]
    frame #12: 0x0000000105e07cf8 DepthCamera`@objc RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.draw(in:) [inlined] DepthCamera.RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.draw(in: __C.MTKView) -> () at <compiler-generated>:0 [opt]
    frame #13: 0x0000000105e07cf4 DepthCamera`@objc RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.draw(in:) at <compiler-generated>:521 [opt]
    frame #14: 0x00000001af4d2380 MetalKit`-[MTKView draw] + 184
    frame #15: 0x00000001af4ce8d0 MetalKit`-[MTKViewDisplayLinkTarget draw] + 40
    frame #16: 0x0000000106368208 GPUToolsCore`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 172
    frame #17: 0x000000019c051f24 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 628
    frame #18: 0x000000019c120608 QuartzCore`display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 268
    frame #19: 0x000000019551ddac CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 176
    frame #20: 0x00000001955487c4 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 60
    frame #21: 0x0000000195547e90 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 448
    frame #22: 0x0000000195542ac8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2144
    frame #23: 0x0000000195541f40 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
    frame #24: 0x000000019f7d2534 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 108
    frame #25: 0x00000001996cd580 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1940
    frame #26: 0x0000000104b8e5b4 ARMail`main at AppDelegate.swift:13:7 [opt]
    frame #27: 0x00000001953c0e18 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Provided all of the backtraces, it seems the final question lies with

**the CoreImage library is crashing on**

```
thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa9601760910)
frame #0: 0x0000000196fce0a0 CoreImageCI::ColorKernelImage::child_count() const + 100
```

**but I don't have access to this.**

It seems that I am sending in the `ciImage` at its current state into `ciContext.render()` then something happens as it goes through, and the memory gets corrupted or something. That's my current best guess.

**Why it is not a dangling pointer:**

It shouldn't be a dangling pointer because I create a new object of the current image called `image` below. So, although `self.videoImage` might change, the `image` is set for this method and the address is different than that of `self.videoImage`. Nothing else is changing `image`.

```
//1) Capture CVPixelBuffer
self.videoImage = ...

//2) Update the MTKView
public func draw(in view: MTKView) {
    if(self.videoImage != nil) {
    let image:CIImage = self.videoImage! //passByValue (to my understanding at least)
    let outputImage = image.applyingFilter("CIBlendWithMask", parameters: parameters) 
    if(renderer.checkRenderCurrentDrawable()) {
        print("Renderer: \(renderer)")
        **//How would there be a dangling pointer for outputImage?
        renderer.update(with: outputImage)
        if(self.finalImage != nil) {
            self.finalImage = outputImage
        }
    else {
        print("Draw nil")
    }
    else {
        print("SVI nil")
}

//3) Render the new image via CIImage
func update(with ciImage: CIImage) {
        // Wait to ensure only kMaxBuffersInFlight are getting proccessed by any stage in the Metal
        // pipeline (App, Metal, Drivers, GPU, etc)
        let _ = inFlightSemaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
        guard
            let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(),
            let currentDrawable = renderDestination.currentDrawable
            else {
                inFlightSemaphore.signal()
                return
        }
        commandBuffer.label = "MyCommand"

        commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler{ [weak self] commandBuffer in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                strongSelf.inFlightSemaphore.signal()
            }
        }
        //Won't ever get here if simulator because I also check this inside RealTimeDepthViewController but neeed to check so the pod will compile
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        #else
        ciContext.render(ciImage, to: currentDrawable.texture, commandBuffer: commandBuffer, bounds: ciImage.extent, colorSpace: colorSpace)

        commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
        #endif
    }
```

**Edit5:**

I have removed `image.applyingfilter()` and magically the errors are a little more narrow.

I am now receiving a `-[CIImage release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15f2a8ca0` and the error is recognizing my `ciImage` as `Dead` which all point to my `ciImage` memory is being freed. However, I'm not sure why. **How do I debug a "message sent to deallocated instance" when "zombies are enabled" is not catching the exact error?**

```
 thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x19562c250)
    frame #0: 0x000000019562c250 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___.cold.2 + 92
    frame #1: 0x00000001955d0f78 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 1120
    frame #2: 0x00000001955d33a0 CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
    frame #3: 0x00000001952ff3f8 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 136
    frame #4: 0x0000000101b91574 DepthCamera`specialized RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.draw(self=0x0000000108018c00) at <compiler-generated>:0 [opt]
    frame #5: 0x0000000101b8bbe4 DepthCamera`@objc RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.draw(in:) [inlined] DepthCamera.RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.draw(in: __C.MTKView) -> () at <compiler-generated>:0 [opt]
  * frame #6: 0x0000000101b8bbe0 DepthCamera`@objc RealtimeDepthMaskViewController.draw(in:) at <compiler-generated>:530 [opt]
    frame #7: 0x00000001af4d2380 MetalKit`-[MTKView draw] + 184
    frame #8: 0x00000001af4ce8d0 MetalKit`-[MTKViewDisplayLinkTarget draw] + 40
    frame #9: 0x00000001020b0208 GPUToolsCore`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 172
    frame #10: 0x000000019c051f24 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 628
    frame #11: 0x000000019c120608 QuartzCore`display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 268
    frame #12: 0x000000019551ddac CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 176
    frame #13: 0x00000001955487c4 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 60
    frame #14: 0x0000000195547e90 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 448
    frame #15: 0x0000000195542ac8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2144
    frame #16: 0x0000000195541f40 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
    frame #17: 0x000000019f7d2534 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 108
    frame #18: 0x00000001996cd580 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1940
    frame #19: 0x0000000100b2a5b4 ARMail`main at AppDelegate.swift:13:7 [opt]
    frame #20: 0x00000001953c0e18 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Comment: how you are creating CIImage object?

Comment: I don't know this language, but instead of all the `if`s can you print each of those (is. Command buffer, currentdrawable, etc) to potentially see which one is MIA?

Comment: Added an edit - check it out. @Sydney - I'm just checking the `nil` or `null` of them. If they were MIA, it would print one of them. I'm not getting a single print statement.

Comment: Are you calling this method async on a DispatchQue?

Comment: I'm calling this method inside `draw()`, I'll post more code. Sec

Comment: Could you try to remove the semaphores for testing?

Comment: I don’t quite get what this has to do with nil. Isn’t this a dangling pointer crash due to a threading mistake?

Comment: I had 2 trains of thought: 1) exc_bad_access can be caused by values that are not correctly declared. I was thinking one of my values could have been nil. 2) Dangling pointer. I have created a _danglingpointer_  section in my code if you want to take a look on my explanation, @matt

Comment: Additionally, this doesn't happen _often_. It could happen. on the 10th image I do this with, or it could happen on the 1000th. It seems quite random when this occurs.

Comment: I enabled zombies to be able to determine where the dangling pointer might be, I continue to only get a `exc_bad_access`, which I assume means any freed memory that becomes a zombie is not actually an issue in this case

Comment: Yeah, okay, that sounds like not a dangling pointer because I’d expect a zombie to speak up.

Comment: So, now my 2 trains of thought are kind of out the window and I'm lost on how to continue debugging this besides the fact that I continue to get bad access errors 

Comment: I'm not sure what the different codes mean, but I have gotten EXC_BAD_ACCESS code errors 1, 2, and 257

Comment: I have updated _Edit5_ with new information. Feel free to check it out - it is now a more narrow problem and we know that the memory for `CIImage` is the issue and is being freed somewhere. However, none of the debug options caught it.

Comment: Okay, so Zombies are working after all and this _is_ a dangling pointer. And what you're seeing is actually what you should expect to see. Dangling pointer errors never happen at the point where the mistake is; they are always "diagnostic", meaning that they are a way of letting you know about a mistake that happened earlier, possibly much earlier. But now, you see, you know it's the CIImage, and you can record retains/releases and see why this CIImage is getting over-released.

Comment: Hrm - intriguing. This is called _without_ zombies even being on. Enabling zombies in itself does nothing. I'm not sure why the `ciImage` is getting released. Without creating another class that subclasses `CIImage` that I can utilize `deinit { }` is there an easier way to debug this issue?

Comment: So, I believe this is a threading problem. Some kind of concurrency or race condition that happens arbitrarily. My current setup creates a variable,  `let image = self.videoImage` and somewhere between threads either `image` or `self.videoImage` is freeing memory somewhere and other threads access is causing issues.

Comment: Any luck with this @impression7vx?

Comment: Yeah - it was a threading problem. I didn't solve it with zombies or any tools - I more or less really dug down into my code to determine the problem and attempt to ensure that there were 0 race conditions. I had to cover every base case that each event could happen before or after the other, i.e. race condition and fix appropriately.